# Question on Dashboard tables

Tags: reporting, dashboard

I'd like to create a table on a dashboard that displays the top 10 Financial Accounts, (custom object) that have a status of 'Submitted - Pending' in the first column and a custom date field called 'Date Submitted' in the second column. The top 10 Financial Accounts shown should show the 10 Accounts submitted longest ago.

Any idea how I can go about creating the report needed to create this dashboard element? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make a report with Financial Account Name & Date Submitted, sort it by date descending (apply status filter as you see fit).

There's no such inline chart option on the report (wouldn't make sense because well, the table is right there)... but you can select "Table" component type in the dashboard editor. Use

```
- Sort rows by
- Maximum values displayed
```

[image: example]

Comment: I created the report with the following columns (I want the extra columns there so a user can drill-down on the dashboard and see more info): Relationship Name (Parent of Fin Acct), Fin Acct Name, Fin Acct Number, Reason for Closing, Date of Submission for Closing Process. I also have  the following filters: Status = Submitted - Closing OR Ready to Close, Row Limit 10 Sorted by Date of Submission for Closing Process Ascending. When I click 'Dashboard Settings', I see the 'Name' options I want, but there are no 'Value' options available. Any idea why this is?

Comment: It is saying: 'Add a number, boolean or summarized field to the report', but I only want it to display a text field (Acct Name) and a date field (submission date) on the table.

Comment: Is it a table or summary report (if you have row limit I think it's table)? Check https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=dashboards_component_table_format_settings.htm - you might have to somehow turn it into summary report. Except there's no way to summarize date fields... Will a numeric formula "TODAY() - Submitted_Date__c" be acceptable to show on the dashboard? :/ Or maybe group the date by week?

Comment: Thanks, yes it is a table report with a row limit. I will look into whether management would be ok with a 'Days Since Submission' field like you suggested. Grouping the date by week is another good option. Thanks again!

Comment: Good luck! In the worst case scenario - Visualforce dashboard component with a link to detail report ;)

Comment: Thanks, ended up going with the formula for 'Days Since Submission' and it seems to be working!